# How to run filter hook inside the action hook for crob job event in WordPress? Any idea

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, wordpress-theming

I am working on cron job event to enable and disable wordpress automatic updates. I prepare cron job event and call this filter action `auto_update_plugin` but i couldn't properly called in functions.php. Cron job event succesfullly works but filter does not `add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin' , '__return_true' , 10 , 2 )`. If I use this filter out side the hook it works but inside the hook it does not work. `ab_automatic_update_cron_true` is a cron event which I am running. any help would be appreciated what I am wrong.

I want to enable and disable wordpress automatic updates. Do you have any suggestion or code please share it.

```
add_action( 'ab_automatic_update_cron_true', 'cw_true_function' , 10 , 2);

function cw_true_function() {         
    return add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin' , '__return_true' , 10 , 2 );   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something like this happen it may be because the add_action comes too late and the action has already been executed.
I don't know if your cron event actually works or not, that's a whole other problem but for your code you could try to edit it like this:

```
if (!did_action('ab_automatic_update_cron_true')){
    add_action( 'ab_automatic_update_cron_true', 'cw_true_function' , 10 , 2);
}else{
    cw_true_function();
}

function cw_true_function() {
    return add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin' , '__return_true' , 10 , 2 );
}
```

This way you are telling wordpress to execute the function if the action has already been executed. Maybe this can point you in the right direction

NOTE: You are telling that your function 'cw_true_function' should accept 2 params (see the 4th param of add action) but you are actually expecting none, is that ok?

Comment: Hi @Diego I tested it out Cron event works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure that your cron event executes this call: do_action('ab_automatic_update_cron_true'); ?

Comment: I think that filter hook does not executed earlier you are right on this one of that reason because filter hook is not loaded properly.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the relevant part of your cron event action, so we have more information to help you

Comment: Yes #Diego I checked it your code does not work.

Comment: add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin' , '__return_false' , 10 , 2 ); if i run this code in functions.php file it works. But when i go to action hook it does not work.